# Recommended way to install glassfish as a service with install4j?

Tags: install4j

We are using install4j version 6.1.5 and I need to install glassfish as a windows service. Therefore I read the documentation and tried to implement a windows service wrapper class to be able to create a service launcher for the installation to use this for the service actions. This is the code:

```
public class WindowsServiceWrapper implements Runnable {
    private static volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

        String glassfishInstallDir = System.getProperty("installation.dir");
        if (glassfishInstallDir == null || glassfishInstallDir.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("Path not set to glassfish installation but required for startup the service.");
            System.exit(1);
        } else if (!new File(glassfishInstallDir).exists()) {
            System.err.println("Path '" + glassfishInstallDir + "' do not exists. Startup of the service aborted.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Starting the service.");

        String asadminPath = glassfishInstallDir + "/bin/asadmin.bat";

        CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(asadminPath + " start-domain");
        runCommand(commandLine);

        // register to jvm shutdown to handle service shutdown
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                keepRunning = false;
                try {
                    System.out.println("Shutdown of the service was triggered.");
                    mainThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        new WindowsServiceWrapper(asadminPath).run();
    }

    private final String ASADMIN_PATH;

    private WindowsServiceWrapper(String asadminPath) {
        ASADMIN_PATH = asadminPath;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning) {
            // nothing to do here but waiting for shutdown hook
        }

        System.out.println("Shutdown the service.");

        CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(ASADMIN_PATH + " stop-domain");
        runCommand(commandLine);
    }

    private static int runCommand(CommandLine cmdLine) {
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        int exitCode;
        try {
            exitCode = executor.execute(cmdLine);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured during command execution: " + cmdLine.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            exitCode = 1;
            keepRunning = false;
        }
        return exitCode;
    }
}
```

To start and stop the glassfish server I used the [commons-exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/index.html) library from Apache. This code works well to install and start the service as well as uninstall the service. There is only one thing left: during the startup of the service I need to wait until the glassfish startup has finished completely and the commons-exec call will be done. It's needed to go ahead with dependent installation steps. For now the "Start Service" action returns immediately. I guess the main method of my wrapper class is instantiated as an unforked thread, is it? So is there a recommended way how to handle things like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "Wait for HTTP server" action to wait until the server has started.